# sqflite's `openDatabase` never ends in tests

Tags: flutter, sqlite, testing, flutter-test, sqflite

I'm writing a Flutter integeration test, which includes opening databases with `sqflite`, the code is as follows:

```dart
import 'package:flutter_test/flutter_test.dart';
import 'package:our_habits/my_app.dart';
import 'package:sqflite/sqflite.dart';


void main() {

  testWidgets("Test sqflite database", (WidgetTester tester) async {
    print("start");
    await tester.pumpWidget(const MyApp());
    print("pumpWidget is done");
    await openDatabase(
        inMemoryDatabasePath,
        version: 1,
        onCreate: (Database db, int version) async {
        }
    );
    print("end");
  });
}
```

As you can see, the code is very simple. However, it doesn't work at all. I noticed that `end` is never printed because `openDatabase` is never finished. Why? How to make it work?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure, you are writing integration tests? Integration test should be in /tests/integration_test folder. When you stored code in other folder Flutter not create full enironment to run test. Look https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/testing/integration/introduction